# Optional enum choose - spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is my seller class

```
    public class Seller {

        private boolean isActive;
        private String name;

//if isActive = true
@NotNull
    @Enumerated
    private ActiveReason reason;

//if isActive = false
@NotNull
    @Enumerated
    private InActiveReason reason2;



    }
```

this is my main entity

```
public class Book {

    private Seller seller;
    private SavingUnit savingUnit;


}
```

From service (UI), they will choose enums.

if `isactive` = true, different reasons will be chosen. If false, different reasons.

Can I use only one enum class and one variable in my `Seller.class`? Like

```
@DependsOnIsActive
private Reason reason
```

I can use maybe validator and in validator, I can use something like this:

```
public class SellerDesctiptionValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SellerDesctiptionValidator, Book> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Book book, Boolean isActive ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
         return Reason.enum (isActive );
     }    
}
```

or what do you suggest? I don't have to use only one enum and one variable. It will be easy with two enums and two variables but I want to improve myself and my code.

Those two reasons, `activereason` and `inactivereason` dont share any common things. They are completely different.

Comment: Do active and non-active share common reasons ? If they are completely distinct sets, I would simply follow [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and keep 2 enums.

Comment: No, they are different reason. Not any common. even, counts of them @Benoit so i can keep 2 enums but what about one variable?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but then both your enums have to implement the same interface. I don't know the use cases for this unique variable, but it seems to me like a bit of over-engineering.